# Google Tag Manager on exit page events performance

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a page with search button, and an tag event that should be fired when the button is pressed.

My question is if the loading of the new page (that should be displayed when the 'search' button is pressed) will be delayed  until after the code in the tag event is finished, or is it done asynchronously somehow

Comment: How is (method of) the search functionality implemented? Is it JS, is it a form post to a different page?

Answer (score 0):

default loading of the new page will be delayed until after the code in the tag event is finished. Tags are usually fired as a listener to click event and they're executed before the default action. However, if your search button has some custom listener that redirects to a new page and overrides the default action then tag may not fire correctly.